# Fake Server Uptime (Linux/Windows)

Tags: linux, windows, time, uptime

Is it possible to fake the server uptime in any way (throttling the time).?(Linux/Windows). I guess it will cause serious troubles, still just wondering.

-Cheers

Comment: Why, do you want this?

Comment: I am not going to try this out anywhere. It is just a question wandering in my mind for a long time and I never had a definitive answer from anyone (so far I asked). I would have really appreciated you guys if you would have simply said "we can't" or "we shouldn't". I thought this place is for knowledge sharing and now I am really disappointed.

Comment: @SparX it's really not appropriate here. Maybe at unix.se or SU. This is a place for knowledge. Very specific knowledge about very specific things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [uptime faker script](http://www.etheus.net/UptimeFaker) that compiles a kernel mod in /tmp that screws with jiffies (the thing that make uptime and everything else tick).

In all likelihood, you'll end up causing your server to implode and create a black hole that will envelope the Earth, so proceed with caution.